# How to get google auth token from authorization code?

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, google-bigquery, access-token

i tried to get the auth token as below:

https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token?client_id=xxxxxxxxx&client_secret=xxxxxxxxxxx&grant_type=authorization_code&code=xxxxxxxxxx&redirect_uri=https://bigquery.cloud.google.com/dataset/projectid:datasetid

Though i already specified the grant_type parameter but still i am getting the below error:

```
 { "error" : "invalid_request", "error_description" : "Required parameter is missing: grant_type" }
```

What is the mistake i am doing here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use HTTP POST and put the values in POST parameters rather than providing them as query parameters in an HTTP GET request.

Comment: how are you sending it; which tool/environment/language?

Comment: commandline curl would look like: `curl -d "client_id=xxxxxxxxx&client_secret=xxxxxxxxxxx&grant_type=authorization_code&code=xxxxxxxxxx&redirect_uri=https://bigquery.cloud.google.com/dataset/projectid:datasetid" https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token` ; you should be able to verify with that

Comment: It worked. Thanks. I was using postman but it was not working there.

Comment: Would you tell me how I can get the value for "code"  parameter ? I just have client_id , client_secret and redirect_uri

Comment: https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?response_type=code&client_id=xxx&redirect_uri=xxx&access_type=offline&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/bigquery  Fill the response_type  and client_id in this url and hit the url in browser. It will give you an option to login via mail id . Select and then you will see a url in browser which has 1 of its parameter as code.